# How to build an update statement to fill in missing data with records that contain that data on multiple column matches?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have thousands of records missing data in 2 columns in a table. I want to fill in those 2 columns using records that have that data by finding matches based on other columns. So use matching data to fill in those missing values.

Sample data:

| maj_id | maj_name | parent_name | child_name | parent_id | parent_id_2 | child_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123456 | XYZ_COMP | xyz_comp_pl | xyz_pl | 987 | 5435 | 20-2 |
| null | null | xyz_comp_pl | xyz_pl_2 | 987 | 5435 | 20-1 |
| 123457 | ABC_COMP | abc_comp_pl | abc_pl | 765 | 5843 | 34-1 |
| 123457 | ABC_COMP | abc_comp_pl | abc_pl_2 | 765 | 5843 | 34-9 |
| null | null | abc_comp_pl | abc_pl_3 | 765 | 5843 | 34-7 |
| null | null | abc_comp_pl | abc_pl_4 | 765 | 5843 | 34-6 |

The null maj_id and maj_name is what I want to have updated with the maj_id and maj_name from columns that having matching parent_name, parent_id, and parent_id_2. I was able to identify records to update using something like the below query, but not sure how to create the update statement out of this.

select t.parent_id
, t.maj_name

from test_table t
inner join
(
select parent_id
, parent_name
, parent_id_2
from test_table
group by parent_id, parent_name, parent_id_2
having sum(case when maj_name is not null then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
and sum(case when maj_name is null then 1 else 0 end) >= 1
)D
on t.parent_id = d.parent_id and t.parent_name = d.parent_name and t.parent_id_2 = d.parent_id_2
order by parent_id, maj_name ASC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO test_table
USING (SELECT b.rowid row_id,
              a.maj_id,
              a.maj_name
         FROM (SELECT parent_id,
                      parent_name,
                      parent_id_2,
                      maj_id,
                      maj_name,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent_id,parent_name,parent_id_2 ORDER BY CASE WHEN (maj_id IS NOT NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC, maj_id DESC) seq
                 FROM test_table) a,
               test_table b
         WHERE a.seq = 1
           AND a.parent_id = b.parent_id
           AND a.parent_name = b.parent_name
           AND a.parent_id_2 = b.parent_id_2
           AND b.maj_id IS NULL) src
ON (src.row_id = test_table.ROWID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET maj_id = src.maj_id, maj_name = src.maj_name
```

Comment: This can of course be done without joining back on the table using LAST_VALUE/FIRST_VALUE on both maj_id and maj_name. There are actually lots of ways to do it.